# Atomikos error prepared transaction "transaction id" with identifier does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, jta, atomikos

I have spring boot app with Atomikos as transaction manager and I see this log:

> ERROR:  prepared transaction with identifier "1096044365_MTcyLjE3LjAuMy50bTAwNDAyMDAwMDE=_MTcyLjE3LjAuMy50bTQwMg==" does not exist

getting printed continuously.

After reading on Atomikos docs I understood that Atomikos has some crash recovery mechanism and I followed this http://fogbugz.atomikos.com/default4343.html?community.6.1918.14 but it didn't solve my issue.

My question is: why does Atomikos attempt to clean up a tx forever? When there's no chance of getting it to commit state.

Below is the stack trace:

> org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: Error rolling back prepared transaction
>       at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.rollback(PGXAConnection.java:419) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.rollback(XAResourceTransaction.java:636) ~[transactions-jta-3.9.3.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.RollbackMessage.send(RollbackMessage.java:70) [transactions-3.9.3.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.PropagationMessage.submit(PropagationMessage.java:83) [transactions-3.9.3.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.Propagator$PropagatorThread.run(Propagator.java:79) [transactions-3.9.3.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.Propagator.submitPropagationMessage(Propagator.java:58) [transactions-3.9.3.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.HeurHazardStateHandler.onTimeout(HeurHazardStateHandler.java:135) [transactions-3.9.3.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.alarm(CoordinatorImp.java:933) [transactions-3.9.3.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.timing.PooledAlarmTimer.notifyListeners(PooledAlarmTimer.java:112) [atomikos-util-3.9.3.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.timing.PooledAlarmTimer.run(PooledAlarmTimer.java:99) [atomikos-util-3.9.3.jar!/:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: prepared transaction with identifier "1096044365_MTcyLjE3LjAuMy50bTAwNDAyMDAwMDE=_MTcyLjE3LjAuMy50bTQwMg==" does not exist
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.rollback(PGXAConnection.java:409) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       ... 12 common frames omitted

How to stop this retry mechanism

This is happening again after updating to 4.0.6

> 2018-01-22 20:42:52.247 ERROR [RequestId:] 1 --- [    Atomikos:51] c.a.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction  : Heuristic termination of XAResourceTransaction: 3137322E31372E302E342E746D313531363637303131363034343030383435:3137322E31372E302E342E746D383435 with state HEUR_HAZARD
>   2018-01-22 20:42:52.247 ERROR [RequestId:] 1 --- [    Atomikos:51] com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp   : Local heuristic termination of coordinator 172.17.0.4.tm151667011604400845 with state HEUR_HAZARD
>   2018-01-22 20:42:52.247 ERROR [RequestId:] 1 --- [    Atomikos:51] com.atomikos.publish.EventPublisher      : Transaction 172.17.0.4.tm151667011604400845 corrupted - check https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/HowToHandleHeuristics to learn more
>   2018-01-22 20:42:52.420  WARN [RequestId:] 1 --- [    Atomikos:51] c.a.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction  : XA resource 'postgres': rollback for XID '3137322E31372E302E342E746D313531363637303131363034343030383435:3137322E31372E302E342E746D383435' raised -3: the XA resource detected an internal error
>
> org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: Error rolling back prepared transaction
>       at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.rollback(PGXAConnection.java:419) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.rollback(XAResourceTransaction.java:460) ~[transactions-jta-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.RollbackMessage.send(RollbackMessage.java:47) [transactions-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.RollbackMessage.send(RollbackMessage.java:20) [transactions-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.PropagationMessage.submit(PropagationMessage.java:67) [transactions-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.Propagator$PropagatorThread.run(Propagator.java:63) [transactions-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.Propagator.submitPropagationMessage(Propagator.java:42) [transactions-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.HeurHazardStateHandler.onTimeout(HeurHazardStateHandler.java:75) [transactions-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.alarm(CoordinatorImp.java:650) [transactions-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.timing.PooledAlarmTimer.notifyListeners(PooledAlarmTimer.java:95) [atomikos-util-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at com.atomikos.timing.PooledAlarmTimer.run(PooledAlarmTimer.java:82) [atomikos-util-4.0.6.jar!/:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: prepared transaction with identifier "1096044365_MTcyLjE3LjAuNC50bTE1MTY2NzAxMTYwNDQwMDg0NQ==_MTcyLjE3LjAuNC50bTg0NQ==" does not exist
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.rollback(PGXAConnection.java:409) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar!/:na]
>       ... 13 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into Atomikos source code and going through the stack traces.
Below is the change I made(in Atomikos source code) to alarm method in CoordinatorImp.java and this solved my issue.

```
public void alarm ( AlarmTimer timer )
{
   try {
        boolean isHeuristic = stateHandler_ instanceof 
          HeurHazardStateHandler 
|| stateHandler_ instanceof HeurAbortedStateHandler
                                  || stateHandler_ instanceof HeurCommittedStateHandler || stateHandler_ instanceof HeurMixedStateHandler;
    if (!(isHeuristic)) {
     stateHandler_.onTimeout ();
    }
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
       LOGGER.logWarning( "Exception on timeout of coordinator " + root_ , e );
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug that has been fixed in TransactionsEssentials 4.0.6

Comment: After version to 4.0.6  for 2 days, it looks like fixed but again I see this issue happening.

Comment: You may want to ask a free trial of the commercial edition then?

Comment: @D7thename were you able to resolve this issue? We are having the same problem.

Comment: No, this is blocking prod release for us.
Right now we're thinking of 2 options. 
1) Trying to look at Atomikos code and find something.
2) If above didn't work then to move away from Atomikos.
Whatever the path we follow will keep posted here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We will look at this as soon as we have time (if you want to raise the priority then please consider a free trial).

Comment: @jan.vdbergh I was able to fix the issue by changing Atomikos code. Were you able to fix it in any other different way?

Comment: @D7thename in our case the problem occurred earlier: the transaction was already rolled back by Postgres during the commit, but it did not indicate that outcome in its XAException. This was solved by modifying the code of the Postgres JDBC driver to correctly map the error.